# How to calculate amount of records that meet and don't meet criteria

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-sql

I would like to calculate amount of teams that have owner (OwnerId!=0) and amount don't have (OwnerId==0).

In plain SQL I would do that using a single query only using 2 sub-queries:

```
select
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teams WHERE User=0) AS FreeTeams,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teams WHERE User!=0) AS UsedTeams
```

Is their any simpler way? How to translate that into Linq2Sql?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var sums =
 (from t in teams
 group t by 0 into g
 select new { freeTeams = g.Count(p => p.User == 0), usedTeams = g.Count(p => p.User != 0) }).SingleOrDefault();
```

This will issue a single query only, but it will require two table scans because L2S fails to translate this efficiently.

We can get this down to one table scan:

```
var sums =
 (from t in teams
 group t by (t.User != 0) into g
 select new { isUsedTeam = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

This will give you two rows, one for freeTeams and one for usedTeams. **Nasty, but the fastest way available with LINQ2SQL.**

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Linq to SQL like this, assuming your `teams` object is set in properly:

```
var freeTeams = teams.Count(p => p.User == 0);
var usedTeams = teams.Count(p => p.User != 0);
```

If you really want a single hit to the database, and are willing to sacrifice some readability, you could use something like this:

```
var counts = from a in teams
    group a by true into aa
    select new
    {
        freeTeams = aa.Count(p => p.User == 0),
        usedTeams = aa.Count(p => p.User != 0)
    };
```

Comment: This will execute two SQL batches. A slight inefficiency.

Comment: @usr given the hoops you need to jump through to get this into a single query in LINQ to SQL I'll take the tiny extra hit in favor of readability any day. Unless someone knows of a clean way to write it that I don't, which is very possible.

Comment: True. I have added my answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

In plain SQL a simpler way is just use `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [User]=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FreeTeams,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [User]<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UsedTeams
FROM Teams
```